# Copying files using SBT

Tags: sbt

I am using SBT for building a java project and have a requirement of copying text files (that are not resources, but used by java classes to read instead).
I am inexperienced with either SBT or Scala (needed for build.scala file)
Any help would be really appreciated.

For example, if my directory structure is:

```
test
    |- files
            |- one.text
    |- main
            |- java
                   |- Test.java
```

I want the one.text file available as well in the target folder once I execute an sbt goal like

```
sbt test
```

Comment: did nau's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Following lines in your build.sbt should do the trick:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+= (baseDirectory) {_ / "files"}

unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test <+= (baseDirectory) {_ / "main" / "java"}
```

You have a non standard project layout though. If you can change it to a standard "maven style":

```
project/src/main/java
project/src/main/resources
project/src/test/java/{Test.java, ...}
project/src/test/resources/{one.text, ...}
```

sbt will do resource copying automatically.

Comment: When I have tried using standard Maven style, my file ("style.css") was copied from "src/main/resources" into target "classes". What can I do to copy it to the target folder directly?