# SBT (Simple Build Tool): Change the build target "classes" directory

Tags: java, scala, tomcat, web-applications, sbt

## Question

For Java web applications, if you put classes where the web server expects them on your development machine, it can save you the step of packaging and redeploying your web-app every time you compile.  It also simplifies things to have the development and deployment directory structure the same.  [Tomcat's Standard Directory Layout](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Standard_Directory_Layout) is:

```
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes
WEB-INF/lib
```

But SBT wants to put all classes in:

```
target/scala-2.10/classes
```

How do I tell sbt to put classes in `WEB-INF/classes` instead?

## Background

So far, I've been using SBT just for unit tests and I run it from `WEB-INF` instead of my project's root directory and don't worry about where it throws the classes because tests don't need to be deployed.  I guess I could wrap SBT in a batch file that cd's to WEB-INF, then cd's back when done, but that seems a little kludgey.

How do people work around this issue?  I could delete `WEB-INF/classes` then [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065064/copying-files-using-sbt) `target/scala-2.10/classes` to it after each build, but that might eliminate some of the benefits of incremental/minimal compilation that SBT offers.

## Extra Credit...

I'm not sure if this is part of a new question, but it falls under "using SBT to build a Java web app" so I'll include it:  Tools like log4j, Struts, proxool, and Hibernate all seem to expect files (and sub-directories recursively) to be copied from `src/main/resources` to `classes` on each build, and I could copy them explicitly the way I do with the Ant build now.  But if SBT had a web-app-defaults, maven-defaults, or java-defaults template or something, that would be helpful to know about.

Comment: Have you had a look at xsbt-web-plugin (https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin)? This could meet your needs. Don't know if it works for sbt 0.13 though.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be

```
target := base / "WEB-INF"
```

or

```
classDirectory := base / "WEB-INF" / "classes"
```