# Annotation Processor output path sbt?

Tags: sbt

Is there any way to set the Annotation processor output path in sbt?

Currently it generates the files into:

`target/scala-2.11/classes`

However I would prefer

`target/scala-2.11/src_managed`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834922/sbt-simple-build-tool-change-the-build-target-classes-directory and similar

Comment: That's not a help at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
// in build.sbt:

// create managed source directory before compile
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn Def.task { (managedSourceDirectories in Compile).value.head.mkdirs() },

// tell the java compiler to output generated source files to the managed source directory
javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-s", (managedSourceDirectories in Compile).value.head.getAbsolutePath),
```

Comment: I had to change it to `javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-s", (managedSourceDirectories in Compile).value.head.getAbsolutePath)`
but then it worked. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Thanks I just overlooked your answer complete.

Comment: btw actually while this works, however on a "cleaner" environement (ie jenkins we get the following: ``` java.lang.IllegalStateException: directory not found: (emitted) /target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main``` any way to solve that?

Comment: Create the directory first, eg, `compile <<= compile dependsOn Def.task { (managedSourceDirectories in Compile).value.head.mkdirs() }`

Comment: actually that will give me an error: `Reference to undefined setting: *:compile from *:compile`

Comment: `(compile in Compile) `

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly more ergonomic to configure `sourceManaged` instead of `managedSourceDirectories`.

Add to a sbt module's settings in `build.sbt`:

```
Compile / javacOptions ++= Seq("-s", (Compile / sourceManaged).value.getAbsolutePath)
```

You can also drop this plugin into the `project` folder

```scala
package custom.sbt

import sbt.{Def, _}
import sbt.Keys._

object Compiler extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def buildSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    Compile / javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "11", "-target", "11"),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-target:11"              // Target JRE 11
    )
  )

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    Compile / javacOptions ++= Seq("-s", (Compile / sourceManaged).value.getAbsolutePath)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in sbt `0.13.15`

```scala
compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn Def.task {
      (sourceManaged in Compile).value.mkdirs()
    }).value,

javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-s", s"${sourceManaged.value}/main")
```